# Select Nth value from each group in Oracle

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables as below

**Table A**

```
Key    Field1  Created_date  
1234    a      Jan-18  
1234    b      Feb-18  
1234    c      Mar-18  
4567    d      Mar-18  
6789    e      Apr-18
```

**Table B**

```
Key Posted_date
1234    Mar-18
4567    Apr-18
```

I want to join table A with B on the field Key and select records with `max(A.created_date)` where `A.created_date < B.posted_date`. The table B has around 300 million records. Could you please help me out.

**Result**

```
Key Field1  Created_date  
1234    b   Feb-18  
4567    d   Mar-18
```

Comment: Which nth value do you want ? Show the complete query which you tried,errors encountered if any

Comment: What output from the query with that input data are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

Various different ways to solve this. Here's a solution which breaks it down into two clear steps so you can understand the principles.

The subquery uses analytic ranking to score the `created_date` for each `key` record in table `A` that matches the criteria in table `B`. The outer filter selects the records from table `A` for each maximum `created_date`.

```
select a.key
       , a.field1
       , a.created_date
from (
  select a.*
         , rank() over (partition by a.key
                        order by a.created_date desc) as rnk
  from b
       join a on a.key = b.key
  where a.created_date < b.posted_date
  ) a
where a.rnk = 1
/
```

Presumably if table `B` has 300 million records then table `A` has more. You will have to experiment to get a version that's sufficiently performative for your needs. For instance, with tables that big we would hope to have licensed the Partitioning option; that might affect how you approach the join and filtering.